# How can I build front-end on AWS EC2 by CodeDeploy?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-code-deploy

I am using Node.js, webpack, EC2, CodeDeploy with BitBucket.
In BeforeInstall script I put:
`#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/papirux/
sudo npm install
sudo NODE_ENV='production' webpack -p`

Deploy was successful.
But folder built by webpack did not appear.
I don't resolve it about two days...

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things that come to mind.

**1. Are you copying your source code to the right directory?**

I would assume that your script would fail if you don't, but are you copying your code to the directory you want via your appspec? It should have a section like this:

```
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/papirux/
```

**2. Look at the logging information for the deployment to see what happened with your script.**

You can see the logging for deployments describe [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html). You should be able to see something useful at `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log` or `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-group-ID/deployment-ID/logs/scripts.log` on your EC2 instance as to what happened with your script. If it failed or copied the files to an unexpected directory, you should see something useful there.

For convenience, you can also install the CloudWatch logs agent and have the logs uploaded to CloudWatch directly.